# Get-Date cast to string vs ToString()

Tags: .net, powershell, datetime

My understanding of PowerShell's string embedding syntax `"$($object)"` has always been that `$object` is cast to `[System.String]`, which invokes `$object.ToString()`.  However, I've noticed this curious behavior with the `[DateTime]` class using PowerShell 4.0 on Windows 8.1.

```
PS> $x = Get-Date

PS> $x.GetType() | select -ExpandProperty Name
DateTime

PS> $x.ToString()
2015-05-29 13:36:06

PS> [String]$x
05/29/2015 13:36:06

PS> "$($x)"
05/29/2015 13:36:06
```

It seems that `"$($object)"` gives the same behavior as casting to string, but is clearly producing a different result from `$object.ToString()`.  `$x.ToString()` is consistent with the short date format set in intl.cpl (yyyy-MM-dd).  `[String]$x` appears to use the en-US default.

It is possible this is simply a bug in the DateTime class, but I'm more surprised that the different methods of converting an object to a string produce different results.  What are the rules for casting an object to a string, if not calling `ToString()`?  Is the DateTime class simply a special case because of its overloading of `ToString(String)`?

Comment: I don't have enough for an answer right now, but I have definitely noticed that `.ToString()` does not always produce the same result as embedding an object in a string (I haven't tested if embedding is always the same as casting to `[String]`). So all I can say is it's not limited to `[DateTime]`.

Comment: `.Tostring()` accepts a format argument, so if you require consistency, always `.ToString()` and provide your desired format.  Meanwhile, agreed that `cast` should just call `.ToString()` and accept whatever it's default format is. Not sure why they would implement it any other way.

Comment: [Probably related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14359053/1630171). I would suspect that casting uses en-US as the default culture either way. `ToString()` OTOH uses the current culture, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: What is the output of `Get-Culture` on your machine?

Comment: Hmmm.. I get the `mm/dd/yyyy` format with `$x.ToString()`.  Though I also get 12-hour time, and with the `[String]$x` I get 24 hour time.   Also worth noting - the cast from `DateTime` to `[String]` must be something supported by Powershell, as it is not valid for C# or other .NET languages.

Comment: Culture is 1033 en-US, but I've used the control panel to update the date (yyyy-MM-dd) and time (HH:mm:ss) formats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an object implements the `IFormattable` interface, then PowerShell will call `IFormattable.ToString` instead of `Object.ToString` for the cast operation. A similar thing happens for static `Parse` method: if there is an overload with `IFormatProvider` parameter, then it would be called.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    public class MyClass:IFormattable {
        public static MyClass Parse(string str) {
            return new MyClass{String=str};
        }
        public static MyClass Parse(string str,IFormatProvider fp) {
            return new MyClass{String=str,FormatProvider=((CultureInfo)fp).DisplayName};
        }
        public string String {get;private set;}
        public string FormatProvider {get;private set;}
        public override string ToString() {
            return "Object.ToString()";
        }
        string IFormattable.ToString(string format,IFormatProvider fp) {
            return string.Format("IFormattable.ToString({0},{1})",format,((CultureInfo)fp).DisplayName);
        }
    }
'@
[String](New-Object MyClass) #Call IFormattable.ToString(null,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
[MyClass]'Test'              #Call MyClass.Parse("Test",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not PowerShell question, but a .NET question. PowerShell scripts can use the .NET structure [datetime] as it is, i.e., PowerShell does not change its behavior.

> What are the rules for casting an object to a string, if not calling ToString()?

Casting uses culture invariant definitions. The `ToString()` method can contain culture dependent implementations, because **it is overridable**.

> Is the DateTime class simply a special case because of its overloading of ToString(String)?

First, DateTime is not a class; it's a structure.
Second, there's no `ToString()` method overloading; **in this case**, the correct denomination is overriding (it is overriding the `Object.ToString()` method).

To understand better what I'm meaning, have fun with these pretty funny date and time printing in different cultures (copy, paste and run):

```
function f{
    $x=get-date
    [CultureInfo]$currentCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('en-US')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('ar-IQ')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('de-DE')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('ru-RU')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('fr-FR')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('zh-CN')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('zh-HK')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('zh-TW')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('hu-HU')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('ko-KR')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('ja-JP')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('ka-GE')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=[CultureInfo]::CreateSpecificCulture('pt-BR')
    $x.ToString()
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=$currentCulture
}

f
```

Notice that the code above will produce different **printing** if run either in ISE or in non-ISE versions of PowerShell.

Comment: I used "Overloading" in this context to distinguish DateTime's `ToString()` from `ToString(formatString)`.  I'm not entirely familiar with the difference between struct and class in .NET.  Is it relevant here?

Comment: Yes, it's confusing. `ToString()` method is the `Object.ToString()` method, which is overridable. But, DateTime **also defines** overloadings to this method, but  `ToString()` method is an overriding, and  `ToString(something)` method is an **overloading**. Classes and structures are quite different, really.