# CRLF using powershell write-host

Tags: string, powershell, write-host

I am trying to output a log file to a variable and use that variable as Body on a Send-MailMessage.
The problem is that all CRLFs in the variable are missing in the output.

ex.

```
$Body = get-content .\TTT.txt
$body
Test
Test1
Test2

write-host "$($Body)"
Test Test1 Test2
```

Is there a way to avoid it? (keep the CRLF)

Answer (score 3):

Documentation gives an answer:

> When writing a collection to the host, elements of the collection are
> printed on the same line separated by a single space. This can be
> overridden with the Separator parameter.

[Write-Host docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host)

Answer (score 3):

If you must use `Write-Host` then add the parameter `-Separator` with Newline:

```
Write-Host $Body -Separator "`n"
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. It works for the write-host. In the case of using it as a body in the Send-MailMessage command, is there a way to do the same?

Comment: depend on the request body requirement, you can convert it to JSON in most cases

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw at [Cannot Get Send-MailMessage to Send Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422494/cannot-get-send-mailmessage-to-send-multiple-lines) the workaround is like this:

```
$Body = @()
$Body += "Test"
$Body += "Test1"
$Body += "Test2"
```

etc

```
Send-MailMessage -To xxx -From xxx -Smtp xxx -Subject "Test" -Body ($Body | Out-String)
```

The above works as I wanted.