# Implicit vs. explicit stringification: Why do string-expanded values sometimes differ from calling [.psobject].ToString()?

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

<sup>**Update**: [@PetSerAl's answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30542422/45375) provides excellent technical background, which I've since tried to summarize in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).</sup>

My understanding of how PowerShell expands (interpolates) scalar values (variable references or subexpressions that expand to a single object) in double-quoted strings is as follows:

- `.psobject.ToString()` is called on the resulting object, which allows PS to provide a custom stringified value, such as for `[pscustomobject]` instances.
- If no custom stringification is applied, the underlying .NET type's `.ToString()` method is called (which in the absence of an overridden `.ToString()` method results in just the *full type name* being returned).

<sup>For a complete overview of PS string interpolation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) of mine.</sup>

However, **there appears to be a third case**:

`[datetime]` instances implicitly string-expand in a way that is distinct from explicitly calling either `.psobject.ToString()` or `.ToString()`.

For instance, on a US English system, as of PSv5.1:

```
# IMPLICIT stringification: string expansion (interpolation)
PS> "$(Get-Date)"
02/13/2017 12:53:42

# EXPLICIT stringification with [.psobject].ToString()
PS> (Get-Date).psobject.ToString()   # (Get-Date).ToString() yields the same
2/13/17 12:54:44 PM   # !! DIFFERENT RESULT
```

Turns out that *casting* to `[string]` behaves the same way as using string expansion (interpolation), so `"$(Get-Date)"` and `[string] (Get-Date)` yield the same.

- What is the underlying implicit stringification mechanism in this case?
- Why does it differ from explicit stringification?
- When and to what types is this mechanism applied?

Comment: Not sure if a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30542422), but definitely related.