# Does PowerShell automatically convert pipeline objects to strings as needed?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

The help for `Split-Path` states that the parameters `-LiteralPath` and `-Leaf` are incompatible:

```
SYNTAX

    Split-Path [-Path] <System.String[]> -Leaf [-Resolve]  # ...

    Split-Path -LiteralPath <System.String[]> [-Resolve]  # ...
```

This command failing confirms it:

```
Split-Path -LiteralPath 'C:\foo.txt' -Leaf
# Split-Path: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
# One or more parameters issued cannot be used together
```

And yet, piping works just fine:

```
Get-Item 'C:\foo.txt' | Split-Path -Leaf
```

Why is that?

I thought `Split-Path` would receive an object from the pipeline and try to bind that object's `PSPath` property to its `-LiteralPath` parameter (alias: `PSPath`), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177977/5405967).

I imagine that because I supplied the `-Leaf` switch, the parameter binder knew to use the parameter set containing `-Leaf`, which took `-LiteralPath` out of the picture.  But then how does `PSPath` end up bound to `-Path`?  Does the binder automatically call `.ToString()` on the object to obtain the path as a string, which it can then bind to `-Path` *by value* instead of *by
property name*?  How does it know to do that?

I tried using Trace-Command, but I'm unable to understand the output.

```
Trace-Command ParameterBinding { Get-Item 'C:\foo.txt' | Split-Path -Leaf } -PSHost
```

Comment: The `Trace-Command` output tells us that the parameter binder initially skips binding the value to `Path` because of type mismatch, but then it tries again _with coercion_ (eg. "convert types if necessary") because there are no other parameters it can bind to given the resolved parameter set, and succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the output of `Trace-Command` when using `-Leaf` (trimmed down here):

```sh
# First, powershell binds any manually specified args (-Leaf):
BIND NAMED cmd line args [Split-Path]
  BIND arg [True] to param [Leaf] SUCCESSFUL

# Then it checks for required positional args
BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Split-Path]
BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Split-Path]

# Because -Leaf was specified, it knows only -Path is required, and tries to bind the object first:
BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Split-Path]
    PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.IO.FileInfo]
    BIND arg [C:\foo] to parameter [Path]
        BIND arg [C:\foo] to param [Path] SKIPPED  ## fails

# It tries again later on by coercing to string and succeeds:
    Parameter [Path] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipeline WITH COERCION
    BIND arg [C:\foo] to parameter [Path]
        COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
        BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
```

Based on the trace output, powershell tries using `named args` > `pipeline, no coercion` > `pipeline, with coercion` *in order*. It tries each with every possible parameter set in the order they're defined in. You can list the parameter sets in order with `(Get-Command Split-Path).Definition`.

- **Without** `-Leaf`, it's able to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter set with no coercion first, so that's what runs.
- **With** `-Leaf`, it excludes the `-LiteralPath` parameter set, and is finally able to use `-Path` by coercing the pipeline object to string.

Comment: Thanks.  And do you happen to know if it coerces by calling the file object's `ToString()` method?

Comment: @MarredCheese Powershell coerces by calling `[string]($object)`, or casting-as-type. Most of the time, this behaves exactly like the `.ToString()` method, but there are exceptions, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30542422/7411885.