# Filling DataSet using SqlDataAdapter is changing the date format

Tags: sql-server, powershell, datetime

I've searched all over the web and am unable to find a solution/guide for my problem.

I'm using the below bit of script its part of a larger script to export multiple SQL tables into CSVs. It fills a dataset with data from an SQL table.

The problem I have is in mainly in relation to datetime settings. For example, If I were to export the SQL table using the export wizard into a CSV file. The date appears exactly like it does in SQL e.g. "2014-05-23 07:00:00.0000000" or "2014-05-23".

However when I use my script it changes the format of the datetime to "23/05/2014 07:00:00" or "23/05/2014 00:00:00". I believe this has something to do with the culture settings of my machine/powershell session.

```
cls

# Declare variables for connection and table to export
$Server     = 'server'
$Database   = 'database'
$Folder     = 'D:\Powershell Scripts\01_Export From SQL\Test Folder'
$Tablename1 = 'test'
$Tablename2 = ''

# Delcare Connection Variables
$SQLconnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SQLconnection.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;server=$Server;Database=$Database"

# Delcare SQL command variables
$SQLcommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT [name] from sys.tables where [name] like '%$Tablename1%' and [name] like '%$Tablename2%' order by [name]"
$SQLcommand.Connection = $SQLconnection 

# Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLcommand 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$null = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SQLconnection.Close()

"Time to Export`tRecords   `tFile Name"
"--------------`t-------   `t---------"

foreach ($Table in $DataSet.Tables[0])
{

    $stopwatch = [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

    $FileExtractUTF8 = "$Folder\FromPSUTF8_$($Table[0]).csv"
    $SQLcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [$($Table[0])]"

    $SQLAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = $SQLcommand 

    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
    $Count = $SQLAdapter.Fill($DataSet)              
    $SQLconnection.Close() 

    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $FileExtractUTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8        

    $stopwatch.stop()

    $Time = "{0}" -f $stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString('mm\:ss\.fff')

    “{0,-14}`t{1,-10}`t{2}” -f $Time,$Count,$Table.name
}
```

The main goal is to export the data from SQL into a flat file with the data appearing exactly as it would if I used the export wizard.

Comment: It's got to be your powershell script, going to need to see that.

Comment: Please see updated post.

Comment: The Export-Csv Cmdlet  just dumps out the file. You will have to output each field in the format that you need.

Comment: Or rather than just doing the select *, use your SQL to format the date like convert(varchar(30),YourDateField,120) as NewDateFormatted

Comment: I've tried that, but it still produces issues. For example, a column data type of Datetime is displayed as "2000-01-01 00:00:00.000" in sql, converting that field to varchar(255) changes the format to "Jan  1 2000 12:00AM". This is done in SQL before it even touches powershell. I'm not applying any styling as my aim is to maintain the original format found in the table.

Comment: What do you mean 'maintain the original format found in the table'? Assuming it's a datetime, it's stored as [days since 1900-01-01 + 300ths of a seconds past midnight](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server/). But you want it to be output as a formatted string date, with varying precision depending on whether there's a time component or not?

Answer (score 4):

## Changing default DateTime format within a script

Within your DataSet / DataTable, the date exists as a `[DateTime]` type. When you export to CSV it needs to be converted to a string so it can be written to file. As you have observed, the default string conversion gives an output such as:

```
[PS]> (get-date).ToString()
21/03/2017 17:52:26
```

The format of this string is specified (as you worked out) by your specific globalization "culture". It appears to be a concatenation of the **ShortDatePattern** and **LongTimePattern** properties of the **DateTimeFormat**.

There are plenty of posts from people who have tried and failed to change the culture of their current session (i.e. the running PS host)...

- [why-does-powershell-always-use-us-culture-when-casting-to-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359053/why-does-powershell-always-use-us-culture-when-casting-to-datetime#14359088)

...but it may be possible to change the globalization culture *within* your script using a mechanism such as the ones described here:

- [powershell-changing-the-culture-of-current-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052765/powershell-changing-the-culture-of-current-session#7052955)
- [Using-Culture function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2380257/5771128)

I suspect you should be able to use the `Using-Culture` example to wrap the `Export-Csv` line in your script.

**But what culture to use?**

So, you might now be able to set a specific culture, but do any of the pre-existing cultures use ISO8601 (sortable) dates? Or more specific formats? It seems not, so you have to make your own!

In short, you need to clone an existing `CultureInfo` and update the `DateTimeFormat`, specifically (at least) the `ShortDatePattern` to be what you want. Here is an example that I hope puts you on the right path. There are two functions, one which clones an existing `CultureInfo` and one which runs a command (`Get-Date`) with the new culture set *for that thread*.

---

```
function New-CultureInfo {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [OutputType([System.Globalization.CultureInfo])]
  param(
    [Parameter()]
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]
    $BaseCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
  )

  $CultureInfo = ($BaseCulture).Clone()

  $CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd"
  $CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.fff"

  return $CultureInfo
}

function Test-DateFormat {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [OutputType([System.DateTime])]
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]
    $Culture
  )

  [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = $Culture
  [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $Culture

  (Get-Date).ToString()
}
```

Example use:

```
[PS]> $NewCulture = (New-CultureInfo)

[PS]> Test-DateFormat $NewCulture
2017-03-21 19:08:34.691
```

---

Now, I haven't been able to run this against an example close to the SQL problem in the OP, but I've had fun working this all out. ;-)

Comment: Look, I'm not gonna pretend I understood that. But I copied and pasted your code at a very later hour of the night into my powershell script which was dumping out 2500 tables. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how in the world I was going to fix 2500 tables with bad dates. This worked like an absolute charm. You're a genius! Thank you. I promise I'll come back and actually try and understand it at some point. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Great description by Charlie. My problem is that I wanted to change the default `ToString` to output an ISO datetime that contains a `T` separator between date and time instead of a space. TL;DR - it's not possible.

I'm more from the Java world than MS but had to write a script to export db CSVs and here's my investigation in case anyone else is interested in how the format is built. I dug into the source code to see how `ToString` works on `DateTime`.

According to the `DateTime` class it will defer to `DateTimeFormat`
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,0a4888bea7300518

```
public override String ToString() {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
    return DateTimeFormat.Format(this, null, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

This will eventually call into `Format` method with a `null` `String` `format`. This causes the block below to be called which basically specifies the `"G"` format to use for the date/time.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs,386784dd90f395bd

```
if (offset == NullOffset) {
    // Default DateTime.ToString case.
    if (timeOnlySpecialCase) {
            format = "s";
    }
    else {
        format = "G";
    }
}
```

This will eventually make a call to get the current Culture's `DateTimeInfo` object that has an internal String pattern that cannot be overridden. It lazily sets this so that it doesn't have to concatenate and there is no way to override it. As Charlie pointed out, it always concatenates `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern` with a space separator.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs,799bd6e7997c4e78

```
internal String GeneralLongTimePattern {
    get {
        if (generalLongTimePattern == null) {
            generalLongTimePattern = ShortDatePattern + " " + LongTimePattern;
        }
        return (generalLongTimePattern);
    }
}
```

So there you have it. Hope it helps the next person know why/how and that it's not possible to override the overall default format - just the date and the time components.